# Generate onclick event on full repeater item template in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, repeater

There are onclick events for buttons, image, linkbuttons. But i need onclick event for full repeater item template. I tried to do that with div but not worked. Please help.

Comment: Use Javascript/Jquery to call server-side method. like $("#Repeater").click(function(){ //Here call server side method synchronously or asynchronously  });

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a>/*do something*/</a>
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater >
```

than you can click on row